# How to stop loop in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

How can i stop the spamming?
I want every member to get only one msg

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  
  message.channel.send (guild.name)
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
      if (member.id != client.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(`testing`).catch(e => console.error(`Couldn't DM member ${member.user.tag}`));
});
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "spamming"? How many times does it send, is it constantly, is it a certain amount?

Comment: My guess is that you are in multiple mutual servers with the bot. This results in multiple messages according to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well according to what I *think* you were trying to do (send a message to all users), this is the code I came up with

```js
await client.users.fetch();
let users = client.users.cache.filter(u => !u.bot);
for (const user of users) {
user.send('testing').catch(e => console.log('…'))
}
```

This code should work, and is easily readable, but please note that you may get **ratelimited** by trying to send messages to a lot of users in DM in a short time.